# Sidebar sliding transition's issue

Tags: reactjs, animation, tailwind-css, sidebar, slidingmenu

I am using react and tailwind css. I am trying to apply a transition to this settings sidebar.

When I click on the icon the sidebar opens but the transition doesn't work. This is the conditional I applied in themeSettings function.

```
import React from 'react'
import {MdClose} from 'react-icons/md'
import {BsCheck} from 'react-icons/bs'
import { themeColors } from '../data/dummy'
import { useStateContext } from '../contexts/ContextProvider'

export default function ThemeSettings() {
    const {setColor, setMode, currentMode, currentColor, setThemeSettings, themeSettings} = useStateContext()
  return (
    <div className='bg-half-transparent font-signika w-screen fixed nav-item top-0 right-0'>
        <div className={`${ themeSettings ? 'right-0' : '-right-full'} w-full shadow-2xl xs:w-[70vw] md:w-[40vw] xl:w-[30vw] h-full fixed dark:text-white dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg bg-white top-0 dark:[#484B52] transition-all duration-300`}>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between p-4 ml-4'>
                <p className='font-semibold text-2xl'>Settings</p>
                <button type='button' onClick={() => setThemeSettings(false)}  className='text-2xl p-3 rounded-full dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-slate-600 hover:bg-gray-400'>
                    <MdClose/>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className='flex-col border-t-1 border-color p-4 ml-4'>
                <p className='font-semibold text-xl'>Theme Options</p>
                <div className='mt-4'>
                    <input type="radio" id='light' name='theme' value='Light' className='cursor-pointer' onChange={setMode} checked={currentMode === 'Light'}/>
                    <label htmlFor="light" className='text-md cursor-pointer ml-2'>Light</label>
                </div>
                <div className='mt-4'>
                    <input type="radio" id='dark' name='theme' value='Dark' className='cursor-pointer' onChange={setMode} checked={currentMode === 'Dark'}/>
                    <label htmlFor="dark" className='text-md cursor-pointer ml-2'>Dark</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='flex-col border-t-1 border-color p-4 ml-4'>
                <p className='font-semibold text-xl'>Theme Colors</p>
                <div className='flex gap-3'>
                    {themeColors.map((item) => (
                       <div className='relative mt-2 curosr-pointer flex gap-5 items-center'>
                        <button type='button'className='h-10 w-10 rounded-full cursor-pointer' style={{backgroundColor: item.color}} onClick={() => setColor(item.color)}>
                            <BsCheck className={`ml-2 text-2xl text-white ${item.color === currentColor ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}/>
                        </button>
                       </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here you can find the context provider where I placed my states

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const StateContext = createContext()
const initialState = {
    cart: false,
    notification: false,
    searchBar: false,
}

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(true)
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(initialState)
    const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState(undefined)
    const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState('#03C9D7')
    const [currentMode, setCurrentMode] = useState('Light')
    const [themeSettings, setThemeSettings] = useState(false)

    const setMode = (e) => {
        setCurrentMode(e.target.value)
        localStorage.setItem('ThemeMode', e.target.value)
        setThemeSettings(false)
    }

    const setColor = (color) => {
        setCurrentColor(color)
        localStorage.setItem('colorMode', color)
        setThemeSettings(false)
    }

    const handleClick = (clicked) => {
        setIsClicked({...initialState, [clicked]: true})
    }

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{ 
            activeMenu,
            setActiveMenu,
            isClicked,
            setIsClicked,
            handleClick,
            screenSize,
            setScreenSize, currentColor,
            currentMode,
            setColor,
            setMode,
            themeSettings, 
            setThemeSettings
         }}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

In the Navbar I trigger the event this way:

`<NavButton customFunc={() => setThemeSettings(true)} icon={<IoMdSettings />} />`

Comment: I've deleted my original answer as I realise the `-right-full` is a legitimate tailwind value.

Have you tried doing a simple test where you replace `themeSettings ? ` with just a simple toggled boolean? See if the animation works when you aren't updating any states. I am just wondering if state changes are causing re-renders or similar.

Comment: Yes it is. I hadn't seen it before. I'll try that out thanks!

Comment: So you are suggesting not to update any state by calling it trough the context provider right? I should create a separate state inside the themeSettings function I guess

Comment: If I place a transition property without updating the state nothing happens, <div className='w-full shadow-2xl xs:w-[70vw] md:w-[40vw] xl:w-[30vw] h-full fixed dark:text-white dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg bg-white top-0 dark:[#484B52] transition-all duration-300}'>

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: I don't think state setting will do anything wrong actually as you aren't reordering any elements so that should be fine.

I did a small pen here to test your classes just with standard javascript, html and tailwind and it seems ok https://codepen.io/oakyden/pen/poGOGyL 

perhaps do a really basic test component as a test, just with the container div and local state.

Furthermore, if your basic example doesnt work  I would suggest this map help https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindui-react, I see its now deprecated and they suggest headlessUI

Comment: I can't sort it out. I tested it everywhere even as a separate component

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong in the context provider

Comment: Maybe the mistake in the app.js

Comment: <div className="fixed sm:static w-full dark:bg-main-dark-bg bg-main-bg navbar">
            <Navbar />
          </div>
        <div>
          {isOpen && <ThemeSettings/>}
          <Routes>